# Cmake error while compiling ArUco libraries

Tags: visual-studio-2013, linker-errors

I am trying to compile ArUCo1.3.0 using CMake GUI 3.2.2.
CMake compiles perfectly fine, generating a Visual Studio 2013 solution. 
But when i build the solution in the Visual studio 2013 i find this error:

```
Error   3   error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\bin\Debug\aruco130.lib' F:\aruco-1.3.0\build\utils\LINK aruco_calibration
```

I am not sure how can i get the .lib file before the project solution is built in VS 2013.

I do not know where am i going wrong.

I have attached a photo of the errors here.[image: Error Window in VS2013]

Tried to google for some answers but all in vain. Help.

Comment: Looks like a bug in ArUCo 1.3.0. Ask it's maintainer. If you are an advanced CMake programmer, you can try to investigate the CMake files.

Answer (score 0):

just downloaded ARUCO 1.3.0 and build by myself. Everything works fine.

According to your error message, maybe you need to fix the opencv dependencies first.